# Where to update WPF observables?

Tags: wpf, observable

Consider a case where I have a WPF application with a StudentView that binds to a property (ObservableCollection) in StudentViewModel. I also have a StudentService that takes a dependency to my StudentRepository. The StudentService provides CRUD operations that are invoked from different contexts other than the UI.

My first implementation has an ObservableCollection in the StudentService. While it works with async invocation and all, this setup is from many aspects fighting back and doesn't feel right. Especially when updating the ObservableCollection from various contexts.

So I'm thinking that a better approach would be to keep Observables in the presentation layer (View/ViewModel) and have the StudentViewModel subscribe to events from the StudentService and then update Observables in the context where they reside.

So my question is, if my revised approach is better or perhaps there are a third option that is even better?

**EDIT with examples:**

Currently I have this (simplified but with the important stuff I think):

View shows a list of students, the DataSource is my ViewModel:

```
ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Students.Result, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">..</ItemsControl>
```

ViewModel:

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
   public NotifyTaskCompletion<AsyncObservableCollection<Student>> Students { get; private set; }

   public MainViewModel(IStudentService service)
   {
      Students = new NotifyTaskCompletion<AsyncObservableCollection<Student>>(service.List());
   }
}
```

The NotifyTaskCompletion is grabbed from Stephen Cleary's article [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn605875.aspx). And the AsyncObservableCollection is grabbed from [here](https://gist.github.com/thomaslevesque/10023516).

My StudentService has this interface:

```
public interface IStudentService
{
   Task<bool> Add(Student student);
   Task<AsyncObservableCollection<Student>> List();
}
```

The IStudentService.Add(...) is invoked from background threads and this must be discovered in the UI.

Now all this works but there are some issues with locking (I think) by the AsyncObservableCollection. So I guess I need a lock from the UI context but then that just feels wrong - having to kinda reference the UI in my service. And what I'm considering is to pull out the AsyncObservableCollection (which is the ObservableCollection) and just return `Task<IEnumerable<Student>>` from my service - and the fire some "OnStudentAdded" events from the service instead...

Hope this makes it more clear?

Thanks.

Comment: What are you using this event for? What changes do you need to know about? What changes in the service?

Comment: As a rule, ObservableCollections belong in the viewmodel. I'd hesitate to put events in the service. The viewmodel should be in control. If you're polling the back end for something, I'd write a class that does that, and I'd give a viewmodel a copy of it. That's not holy writ, but I find that approach is easiest for me to write and maintain.

Comment: @FCin I've added some more explanation and examples.

Comment: @EdPlunkett why would you not use events in the service? Are there some more elegant way of letting the UI know about changes?

Comment: @Werner *"I guess I need a lock from the UI context but then that just feels wrong - having to kinda reference the UI in my service"* -- so don't. The way I'd do it, the service just barfs up data somebody asks for -- `List<POCO>`. If the VM wants to ask for it in a background worker, or put viewmodel versions of that PCOO in an observablecollection, that's up to the VM. As I said, this is not holy writ. The approach I describe may be too rough and ready if you've got a lot of clients that need to keep synchronized with each other. But don't commit to the extra complexity if you don't need it.

Comment: @EdPlunkett that is exactly the kind of recommendations I'm after. I have very little experience dealing with UI integrations. So I'm very interested in how you guys deals with it. There are not many reference examples out there. At least not covering the above scenario: ViewModel getting data async where data is pumped in from other threads...which is kinda weird because that sounds like a common setup. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The service needs to somehow notify the view model whenever new items are added or removed. I agree that it is better to do this by either raising events from the service class or by exposing an `IObservable<T>` that the view model can subscribe to.

If you expose a public `ObservableCollection<T>` property from the service that the view binds directly to, you won't be able to update this collection from a background thread in the service class. The service gets somewhat of a dependency upon the client.

Binding directly to properties exposed by a service class is rarely a good idea. You could create a copy of the collection in the view model and bind to this one, but then you still need to synchronize this collection with the one defined in the service and this is not any simpler than subscribing to an event or an `IObservable<T>` and update the data-bound source collection "manually" in the view model.

Comment: Thanks, I've added some example code that more shows my issue. Would you recommend Rx over ordinary events in my case?

Comment: No, I wouldn't. There is no reason why you can't simply raise an event when a new Student is added.